# How do I install the standalone Android SDK and then add it to IntelliJ IDEA on Windows?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

This is the webpage showing from where I downloaded the SDK:

[image: This is the webpage of the downloaded SDK]

On extracting the .zip folder, and opening the '*tools*' folder, all I can see in an emulator.exe, mksdcard.exe and a host of .bat files (as shown below).

[image: This is the folders contents.]

*How do I proceed?*

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? Do you need some other answer?

Comment: Nope... Strangely I cannot choose the SDK installation path in IntelliJ Idea's Settings. When I click on the drop down menu in the path selection, it is null. (The Explorer directory view is not appearing)

Comment: Did you add Android SDK Platform using the [+] button like shown on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqfwv.png)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 and 2017.2 setting up Android SDK from scratch is complicated. I would recommended to install Android Studio and manage SDK platform there. This problem will be addressed in one of the nearest updates.

If you are brave enough, it's still possible to set it up without Android Studio using the `tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat` command line tool. GUI version of the SDK Manager is deprecated (no longer available in the SDK download). Standalone SDK can be downloaded [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads). Look below the **Get just the command line tools** section.

So, you will need to install at least one platform version.

First run the update to ensure you have the latest tools:

```
sdkmanager --update
```

Now you can list the packages available for installation:

```
sdkmanager --list
```

To install Android Platform: (Edit April 2022: need quotes now)

```
sdkmanager "platforms;android-26"
```

To install the current build tools version (optional):

`sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.0"`

At this point you should be able to add Android SDK configuration for the installed platform version in IntelliJ IDEA like this:

[image: Android SDK]

You will also have access to Android SDK configuration UI where you download additional components and perform updates (just like in Android Studio):

[image: Android SDK UI]

Comment: Google endorses Android Studio which is _built_ on (or rather a degenerated from of) IntelliJ Idea, and still there is not a streamlined method to do it. The fact that it is not updated to IJI can be understood well that _it still has a Eclipse SDK Monitor_ at **C:\Android\tools-sdk\lib\monitor-x86**

Comment: They probably keep it intentionally until all the functionality of the Monitor is available inside the IDE.

Comment: Do the updates to the standalone SDK involve JetBrains in any way? Or is it only Google and its community?

Comment: All the Android SDK components are managed entirely by Google. JetBrains merges only IDE related code from Android Studio repository.

Comment: While installation I noticed that there was a warning as: '.android\repositories.cfg cannot be loaded' in multiple instances. Is this because I did have an SDK installed previously and I'm trying to _update?_

Comment: Not sure, probably you have multiple instances of the `sdkmanager` running.

Comment: Using IntelliJ 2018.2 and it doesn't seem that you can do this form the IDE yet.

Comment: The command `sdkmanager platforms;android-26` didn't work for me. I had to use `sdkmanager "platforms;android-26"`

Answer (score 15):

As **Karan Sharma** mentioned in [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191163#comment=27-2850768) post.
To add an existing SDK, you should close your project if you have any open one. 
[image: close your project]

Then from the Welcome page select Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure
[image: Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure]

And then from the **Default Project Structure** window and from the left side, select **SDKs** and then the plus button from the toolbar, and from the menu select **Android SDK**
[image: Select Android SDK option from the Menu]

And then give the address to the location where your Android SDK files are in, and hit OK.
[image: Final result]

Thats it!
Now it should be working for you!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: A bit out of date:  Appearance&Behavior >> System Settings >> Android SDK  : Probably the best bet is to just search for "Android" from the Settings panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install the SDK in the IDEA GUI. It says in the tutorial,

> If you don't have the Android SDK configured, IntelliJ IDEA will
> detect this and prompt you to download it:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

launch android executable and install the platforms and build-tools.

Comment: Which .exe specifically? (see the second image for help)

Comment: android.bat, it is seen on your screenshot

Comment: do you run it from console? what is the error you get?

Comment: '.android\repositories.cfg cannot be loaded'