# Can't set Android SDK on Intellij Idea, won't let me edit it. Do I need Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I know this may be a really noob question, but Intellij Idea won't let me set the path for my Android SDK. I've been using for Java with JDK, but I can't even edit the path. What's happening? I've searched lots of tutorials and all them just say "set up the path at settings"

Also, do I need to install the downloaded SDK or I just need to set up the path for it?  Do I need Android Studio?

Even https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html won't tell me how to install the SDK. Also, if I run `android_sdk/android`, I get a message saying that this method is deprecated. What should I do????

[image]

Comment: Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268592/104891.