# IntelliJ IDEA Android SDK Linux / Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I installed Intellij IDEA community from JetBrains using the JetBrains Toolbox on Ubuntu 16.04.
Now I wanted to create an Android project (`File --> New --> Project... --> Android`), but I got the error `Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 24.0.2 or later. You can configure your SDK via Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs`.
However, I cannot find `Configure` in the menu bar.

According to: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prerequisites-for-android-development.html I downloaded the Android SDK tools for Linux, but what should I do with these? The instructions on that page are only for Windows.

According to: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-android-development.html , which refers to: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-sdks.html for configuring Android SDK to work in IntelliJ IDEA. That page shows how you select the SDK for Java, but I'm trying to create a New Project Android Studio, which doesn't let me select an SDK.

How do I add Android SDK to IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Why don't you use directly android studio ? who is a version of intelliJ IDEA create for android development .

Comment: Maybe in the future I want to transform my code to JavaScript (going to use Kotlin) and I'm frustrated that, while this should be easy since Google and JetBrains collaborate, I'm still struggling so much with it.

Comment: Agree, it's seem so difficult to do that, sorry i can't help you.

Comment: @NumesSanguis please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268592/104891 for the solution.