# selected directory isn't a valid home for Android SDK - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, path

I want to write apps for android but I'm having an unresolved problem by installing IntelliJ IDEA.

The installation runs good, but always when I try to select the Android SDK, I get the *famous* error: **The selected directory is not a valid home for Android SDK**

[image: error]

I tried many ways to resolve it.

- I read other tasks on SO but nothing helped me very well.
- I adapted the system environment variables
- I tried different paths (like *C://User/AppData/Local/Android/SDK* and *C://Program Files/Android/SDK*)
- I checked the path for mistakes (like blanks)
- I uninstalled the program (for round about three times)
- I restarted my pc
- I restarted the program
- checked if all is correct (and it was. Every time.)
- I run as administrator
- I checked if the files are writeable

I tried Android Studio of course too, but the error occurs nonetheless.

Here are my PC Specs:
 - Have an Asus ZenBook
 - i7-7500U CPU
 - 8GB RAM
 - Win10 Home

I really hope you can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are mentioning root directory when you are adding platform?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268592/104891.

Comment: @crazyCoder I tried this already, but didn't work for me in android studio and intellij idea

Comment: @Sam Yes I do of course

Answer (score 1):

In **Android Studio** go to `File->Settings->Syestem Settings->Android SDK` than click on Android SDK Location **Edit button** It'll auto-detect SDK location in your system if SDK not found than download window will open and from there download SDK. For your ease see the below image.

[image]

Comment: What you've got through this process?

Comment: invalid path to sdk folder