# problems with Intellij and Android SDK

Tags: android, intellij-idea, freeze

I want to develop an Android app using Intellij, as Android Studio is based on it,but when I try to set the project, it tells me that I have no Android SDK installed and when I give the path to the already installed Android SDK it freezes at the installation.it freezes when I try to Reinstall the SDK too.I tried the solutions proposed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1672)  but none of them is working .Is there any Solution to this probleme or should I just use Android Studion instead?

Comment: apart from that, I believe you would be better to use Android Studio, it's not only about the SDK but also about a lot of features and functionalities that will ease your work in Andoid Development and you will find in Android Studio, the guys in JetBrains separated Android Sudio from Intellij IDEA for a reason.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268592/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoderThank you,and as you stated in that Post, I'm brave enough to set it up without Android Studio